# s3.getObject inside lambda doesn't return anything the first time its run but does after that

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, sdk

I have the following code inside a lambda function

```
 var objectData = [];

"GetResearchBlogIntent" : function(){

var bucketParams = {
  Bucket: "etfs-alexa-app",
  Key: "researchBlogs/IndonesiaSecuresMajorityStakeInGrasbergMine.txt"
}

s3.getObject(bucketParams, function(err, data){

     if (err){
       console.info( "Error", err);

     }

     else{
   objectData.push(data.Body.toString("utf-8"));


     }

 })
this.emit(":ask", objectData )}
```

This will return nothing the first time you run it but will return the correct information from the text file in the on s3 no matter how many times you run it unless you completely reset it.

I don't understand how to make the lambda wait for the s3.getObject to get the information.

I have tried:

```
 "GetResearchBlogIntent" : function(){
    var bucketParams = {
      Bucket: "etfs-alexa-app",
      Key: "researchBlogs/IndonesiaSecuresMajorityStakeInGrasbergMine.txt"
    }

    s3.getObject(bucketParams, function(err, data){

      if (err){
        console.info( "Error", err);

      }

      else{
        objectData.push(data.Body.toString("utf-8"));
        console.info("4")
        context.succeed()
      }

    })
    this.emit(":ask", objectData )
  }
```

but i don't think i am doing this correctly as it just gives me the error context not defined which it is here:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context, callback);
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
  };
```

I have also tried using callbacks but in am not sure of the correct syntax when using the SDK library.

Comment: Why don't you have `this.emit(":ask", objectData )}` in the `else` block?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to have `objectData`  after the call to `getObject` completes successfully ?

Comment: I get an error saying the response is invalid if i have the this.emit(":ask", objectData ) in the else block.

Comment: Could you please post the stack-trace

Comment: Yes i think so though i am not sure how to do that. As context.success doesn't work for me.

Comment: What do you intend to do using `emit`? If you think, emit will return data from a `lambda` function, it won't

Comment: I can't fit the stack trace into the comments but the error is this. TypeError: this.emit is not a function at Response

Comment: Don't i need to emit the data so that the text can be read out loud when some uses the correct utterance ?

Comment: Replace `function(err, data){` by `(err, data) => {`
` This is a problem of context

Comment: i am still getting: The response is invalid  when using this  s3.getObject(bucketParams, (err, data) =>{

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing an asynchronous problem. You were calling `emit` when the `getObject` didn't even started, that's why you got an empty `object`.

---

Either call the emit inside the `getObject`.

```
      s3.getObject(bucketParams, (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            // ...
          } else {
            objectData.push(data.Body.toString("utf-8"));

            context.succeed();

            this.emit(":ask", objectData);
          }
        });
```

---

Either, wrap the `getObject` inside a `function`, and then call the `emit` at the end of it.

Comment: sorry i wasn't quite sure if you meant the emit inside or outside of the function wrapped around the s3. so i tried both ways when i left i outside it didn't make any difference and inside i got an invalid response error when i tested it.

Comment: So it means that you are actually emitting the data. Now I guess there is an error about the data you are sending (`objectData`). You should look if it match the related documentation.